# Read contents of file from puppetserver uri

Tags: puppet

I know I can read the contents of a file using

```
$var = file("some_path)
```

In puppet, but when I try and pass in a path that is a puppet file server uri it can't seem to find it. Is it possible in puppet 4.2.2 to do

```
$var = file("puppet:///...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The `puppet://` style URLs are meaningful only to the `source` property of the `file` type.

```
file { '/etc/my_custom_config':
    source => 'puppet:///modules/my_custom_module/etc/my_custom_config'
}
```